# creating rss.xml file for wordpress posts

Tags: xml, wordpress, rss

I'm researching at google for hours, but could not find anything :/

how can I create **rss.xml** for my wordpress blog?

I do not mean feed://www.blabla.com/blog/feed/ ! I need the posts in .xml format. how can I create such .xml for my wordpress posts?

> I need
>   **http://www.blabla.com/blog/rssfeed.xml**
>
> NOT feed://www.blabla.com/blog/feed/

For example msnbc has such file http://rss.msnbc.msn.com/id/3032091/device/rss/rss.xml

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by XML format? RSS is XML based.

Comment: i need to www.blabla.com/rssfeed.xml format file. i have sth to do with php :/

Comment: The response from `feed://www.blabla.com/blog/feed/` is (most likely) XML in RSS format. I don't understand the question.

Comment: You mean, you want to use a different URL to access the feed?

Comment: i need to get last few blog post with php to an another website's homepage. I can take post from blabl.xml with php.

Comment: like $xmlDoc->load(http://rss.msnbc.msn.com/id/3032091/device/rss/rss.xml); works well.... but $xmlDoc->load(feed://www.blabla.com/blog/feed/); does not

Comment: Change `feed://` to `http://` - the `feed` bit is to tell a client system to use the user's default news reader (which then uses HTTP), but your xmlDoc object won't recognise that format.

Comment: I think the question is trying to get at the fact they need a physical .xml file and not just a path.  I've ran into this issue while trying to run a wordpress feed into a Cognos Portal front-end.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add external RSS feeds to your Wordpress blog? [WordPress › FeedWordPress « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/feedwordpress/)

Answer (score 0):

Listen to what others here are telling you. Your WordPress site provides XML through the /feed url on your site. If the admin of the other site is telling you that it won't work then find a more knowledgeable person on that end to do the implementation.